# Why does Google Optimize experiment segment show error message while trying to access behaviour flow?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, optimization, filtering, advanced-segments

I have a simple question whenever I try accessing behaviour flow with an Experiment ID with variant segment it gives me this error message - **This segment contains constraints that cannot be applied to this report.** Why is that?

However, I get this message for only one of the variants and I would like to know why is that. I would like to compare them both on specific steps of the flow.

[image]